# Retrieve data from a grouped query in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Suppose I have this set of data:

```
id    name     amt
1     john     5
1     john     13
1     john     6
2     doe      3
2     doe      4
3     sue      5
3     sue      10
```

I want to extract a data that would look like this

```
name      amt
john      5
          13
          6
doe       3
          4
sue       5
          10
```

How do i generate this using Laravel Eloquent query?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom queries like as

```
DB::table('table_name')
    ->select('name',DB::raw('group_concat(amt)'))
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->get();
```